# Can we choose a $\lambda$ small enough so that, $\frac{\delta^c(\log(\delta^{-1}))^c}{\delta^{\lambda}}\le \delta^{c_{0}}?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Fix a constant $c>0$ and $0<\delta<1$ . Can we choose a $\lambda$ small enough so that there exists a constant $c_0$,
$$\frac{\delta^c(\log(\delta^{-1}))^c}{\delta^{\lambda}}\le \delta^{c_{0}}?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Always is $\delta(\log(\delta^{-1}))\in(0,1)$ (draw plot and see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+xlog%281%2Fx%29), so also  $\mu:=\delta^c(\log(\delta^{-1}))^c\in (0,1)$. Choose $\lambda$ such that $\frac{\mu}{\delta^\lambda}<1$ which is possible e.g. when $\frac{log(\mu)}{log(\delta)}\geq\lambda$. Then, the left side $$LS:=\frac{\delta^c(\log(\delta^{-1}))^c}{\delta^{\lambda}}<1$$ and therefore there exist your $c_0$ e.g. when  $c_0\leq \frac{\log(LS)}{\log(\delta)}$.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean that take $c_0$ so that $\delta^{c_0}\ge LS$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. When LS<1 then you then there exist $c_0$ such that $\delta^c_0\geq LS$.

Answer (score 1):

We have, $$(\delta \ln (\frac {1}{\delta}))^c<{\delta}^{c+\lambda}$$
Taking log with base $\delta$ on both sides(note that inequality sign will have to be reversed as $\delta<0$), we get:
$$c (\log_{\delta}(\delta \ln (\frac {1}{\delta}))-1)>\lambda$$
So, you have got the required range of $\lambda$.